# Using custom SSL certificates in titanium web proxy

Tags: c#, titanium-web-proxy

I have used Titanium web proxy for a windows forms application and there, I intercept https traffic and update it. I have first used titanium root certificate and it worked fine.
 when I was trying to use custom ssl certificate as below

```
proxyServer.CertificateManager.RootCertificate = new X509Certificate2("default.pfx", 
                    "password",
                    X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

proxyServer.CertificateManager.TrustRootCertificate(true);
```

but I couldn't able to decrypt the https traffic and it says

```
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." innerException says "  
Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."
```

how to decrypt the https traffic using custom ssl certificate in [titanium-web proxy.](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy/wiki#custom-root-certificates)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed when I add custom certification name and issuer name to proxyserver constructor and didn't needed any of above code. just fixed the issue by below code and certificate needs to installed in the machine

```
ProxyServer proxyServer = new ProxyServer("certificate.pfx", "Issuer Name",true,true,true);
proxyServer.CertificateManager.PfxPassword = "Password";
```

Comment: It would be great if you name the Custom Certificate Provider, I am also looking into this option to include a custom certificate.

Comment: This doesn't work, any other ideas?